# Syntax error in FROM clause in ASP.net vb while querying csv file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, oledb

In my ASP .NET application (using vb.net), I am getting error "syntax error in FROM clause" while querying a csv file using OLEDB connection.

```
   connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & 
   Server.MapPath(strFolderPath) & ";Extended 
   Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)"";"

   conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
   query = "SELECT * FROM " & FilePath
   'File path is C:\DEV\Uploads\file.csv
   cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
   da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
   ds = New DataSet()
   da.Fill(ds, "Putaway") 'here throwing error
```

Please how to solve it.

Comment: CSV files are text files with commas, not databases. You *don't* need OLEDB to read them. If you do, `FROM` refers to the sheet or named table/range, not the file. It's a lot faster and easier to use a CSV library instead of OLEDB though, and has none of the 32/64-bit problems the JET engine does

Answer (score 0):

For starters, don't use OLEDB to read CSV files. CSV files are just text files with Values Separated by Commas. Nothing more. You can read the data as text, or use a library like CsvHelper that parses CSV files and can even wrap them in a DataReader.

For example, using CsvHelper's [CsvDataReader](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/csvdatareader/) class you can replace your code with :

```
Using reader As New StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv")
    Using csv As new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Using dr As new CsvDataReader(csv)
           Dim dt As new DataTable()
            dt.Load(dr)
            ...
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

This code will work both on Windows and Linux, both for 32-bit and 64-bit applications

The Access driver used in this code has several problems and is avoided in web applications. It was created to allow Office applications to read Access and Excel and CSV files, not for general use. CSV files are supported in a quirky way

1. It requires installing the ACE engine
2. OLEDB only works on Windows, so can't work at all in ASP.NET Core
3. The ACE engine must match the web app's bitness (32/64-bit). Worse, you can't install both versions at the same time.
4. The ACE's bitness must match any installed Office applications.

That driver treats a folder as the "database" and file names in that folder as table names. That means that `FilePath` must be `file.csv`, not the full path `C:\DEV\Uploads\file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue when directly used the csv file name without fullpath.

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM file.csv"
 'File path is C:\DEV\Uploads\file.csv
```

Comment: When using OLE DB to read files, the folder is treated like the database, so its path goes in the connection string, and each file is treated like a table, so its name goes in the query.